# Сортировка по возрастанию

Tags: c

Задача на C: "Задана строка, содержащая целые числа (максимум 15 чисел). Упорядочить целые числа в строке  по возрастанию."

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, str[15];
    for (i=0; i < sizeof str/sizeof(int); i++)
        scanf ("%d", str+i);
    for (i=0; i < sizeof str/sizeof(int)-1; i++)
        for (j=i; j < sizeof str/sizeof(int); j++)
            if (str[j]<str[i]) {
                int w;
                w = str[i];
                str[i] = str[j];
                str[j] = w;
            }
    for(i=0; i < sizeof str/sizeof(int); i++)
        printf(" %d", str[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Сойдёт на тройку?

Comment: На двойку, если специальность тесно связана с программированием :-)

Comment: Да ладно вам. Если убрать бесконечные sizeof на sizeof-е sizeof-ом погоняет, то на тройку сойдёт всё же :D Хотя, над сортировкой подумать не мешает, а то очень уж школьное решение: я так в девятом классе сортировал :D

Answer (score 1):

Советую вам ознакомиться с типичными [алгоритмами сортировок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC&%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0/). Применив любую из них, вы получите решение.

Answer (score 1):

Обижають, в учебники тычуть. Оценку снижають. А я всего-то хотел вопрошающему помочь.
Ну вот вам из учебника (какого - не помню, так же как и название алгоритма):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void sort1(unsigned int m, unsigned int *b, unsigned int *e) {
    unsigned int *b1, *e1, m1;
    b1 = b; 
    e1 = e;
    while(b1 < e1) {
        if(*b1&m) 
           if(*e1&m) e1--;
           else {
              unsigned int w;
              w = *b1;
              *b1 = *e1;
              *e1 = w;
           } 
           else b1++;
        }
        m1 = m >> 1;
        if(m1) {
        if((*b&m) == (*e&m)) sort1(m1, b, e);
        else {
            if((*b&m) != (*b1&m)) --b1;
            if(b1 > b) sort1(m1, b, b1);
            if(e > b1 + 1) sort1(m1, b1+1, e);
        }
    }
 }

void sort(const unsigned int n, unsigned int str[]) {
   unsigned int i, m;
   for(i=1, m = str[0]; i < n; i++) m = str[i] > m ? str[i] : m;
   while(m) {
       i = m;
       m &= m - 1;
   }
   sort1(i, str, str+n-1);
}
int main() {
  unsigned int n, i, m, str[15];
  n = 0;
  while(n < sizeof str/sizeof(unsigned int) -1 && (i = scanf("%td", str+n++)) != EOF) {}
  if (i == EOF) --n;
  sort(n, str);
  for (i = 0; i < n; ) printf(" %td", str[i++]);
  return 0;
}
```

И что, оно вам больше нравится?